# Fast way to plot mutliple rows of a pandas dataframe according to specific column values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a time series dataframe looking somewhat like:

```
A = 
date,uuid,diesel,e5,e10
2018-01-31 00:01:06+01,c03c846e-64ec-437f-9a52-9eda8088c4b2,1.239,1.419,1.399
2018-01-31 00:03:06+01,6dc575da-3c85-430c-a17a-6efdae0dcf5a,1.249,1.419,1.399
```

where date is the index and (optionally parsed as datetime).

The dataset is pretty big (>100.000.000 lines) containing roughly 15.000 unique `uuid`s.

I want to plot either how the price (for diesel,e10,e5) changed over time for every single uuid (=gas station) or just for some random sampled number (like 10 or 100).

Currently I am doing this with a loop, but as looping is very slow in pandas I would like to know if there is a faster maybe vectorized technique:

```
for count,uuid in enumerate(dataframe.uuid):
    x = dataframe.loc[dataframe.uuid == uuid].index
    # diesel
    ax1.plot(x, dataframe.loc[dataframe.uuid == uuid].diesel)
    # e10
    ax2.plot(x, dataframe.loc[dataframe.uuid == uuid].e10)
    # e5
    ax3.plot(x, dataframe.loc[dataframe.uuid == uuid].e5)
    if count >= cap-1:
        break
plt.show()
```

**EDIT:**

after correctly grouping by `uuid` and `date` the dataset looks promising to what i want do: `dataframe.groupby(['uuid','date']).sum()[['diesel','e10','e5']]`

```
                                                               diesel   e10     e5
station_uuid                            date            
00006210-0037-4444-8888-acdc00006210    2018-01-01 06:33:06     1.189   1.369   1.389
                                        2018-01-01 06:39:05     1.189   1.329   1.349
                                        2018-01-01 09:39:07     1.189   1.319   1.339
...
```

how can i now plot the price change over time for all or a selected number of `uuid`s ?

Comment: have you tried something like `dataframe.groupby('uuid').diesel.plot()`

Comment: Try https://seaborn.pydata.org/ - I don't know if it is suitable for very large datasets, though

Answer (score 0):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure(1)

grouped_dfs = dataframe.groupby('uuid')

plt.subplot(311)

grouped_dfs.plot.line(x='date', y='diesel', color='blue')

plt.subplot(312)
grouped_dfs.plot.line(x='date', y='e10', color='red')

plt.subplot(313)
grouped_dfs.plot.line(x='date', y='e5', color='yellow')

plt.show()
```

without any data to play around with, this is the solution I have off the top of my head

Comment: you can get the data from: git clone https://tankerkoenig@dev.azure.com/tankerkoenig/tankerkoenig-data/_git/tankerkoenig-data

Comment: your code does not compile. x='date' does not work as date is a datetimeindex.
`
changing it to 
    plt.figure(1)
    grouped_dfs = dataframe.groupby('station_uuid')
    x = dataframe.index
    
    plt.subplot(311)
    grouped_dfs.plot.line(x=x, y='diesel', color='blue')

    plt.subplot(312)
    grouped_dfs.plot.line(x=x, y='e10', color='red')

    plt.subplot(313)
    grouped_dfs.plot.line(x=x, y='e5', color='yellow')

    plt.show()
`
also does not work.

Comment: I just looked at the link and i don't think you can show ALL the plots at the same time with all that data.